# jQuery Datatable, Cant' stop sorting on selected columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to remove sorting from some columns in a jQuery data table and can't get it to go away.I am using a repeater to populate the table. I set orderable, sortable and searchable to false for the two columns I am trying to remove sorting but it still shows the sorting arrows.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTableData" OnItemCommand="rptTableData_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div id="divFCTable">
            <table id="fcTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Certificate</th>
                        <th>Response Due Date</th>
                        <th>Frequency</th>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Requires Attachment</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
                    <tfooter>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Certificate</th>
                            <th>Response Due Date</th>
                            <th>Frequency</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <th>Requires Attachment</th>
                        </tr>
                </tfooter>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbDetails" CommandArgument='<%= Eval("CertItemName") %>' Text="Respond" />
                            </td>
                            <td runat="server" id="tdCertItemName"><%# Eval("CertItemName") %></td>
                            <td runat="server" id="tdResponseDueDate"><%# Eval("ResponseDueDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %></td>
                            <td runat="server" id="tdFrequency"><%# Eval("Frequency") %></td>
                            <td runat="server" id="tdQuestionText"><%# Eval("QuestionText") %></td>
                            <td runat="server" id="tdRequireAttachment"><%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("RequireAttachment")) ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                        </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        table = $('#fcTable').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            order: [[2, "asc"], [1, "asc"]],
            "columnDefs": [
                { "sortable": false, "targets": [0,4] },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": [0,4] },
                { "searchable": false, "targets": [0,4] }
            ],
            select: true,
            processing: true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                if (moment(new Date()).isAfter(data[2], 'day')) {
                    var $cell = $('td:eq(2)', row);
                    $cell.css('color', 'red');
                    $cell.attr('title', 'Overdue Response Submission');
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It will be done by  `$('#fcTable').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );` `https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering`

Comment: would that completely remove ordering? If so, I just need to remove ordering for two columns: column 0 and column 4.

Comment: Yes it will set it on all columns. For individual columns please follow `https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data` and set it like `"columns": [
    { "data": "ColumnName", orderable: false }
  ]` @NoBullMan